# Python matrices code meaning snippet

Tags: python

I was wondering what the for lines in this code are supposed to do. This is a snippet of code I need help with:

```
# iterate through rows of X
for i in range(len(X)):
   # iterate through columns of Y
   for j in range(len(Y[0])):
       # iterate through rows of Y
       for k in range(len(Y)):
           result[i][j] += X[i][k] * Y[k][j]

for r in result:
   print(r)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code multiplies matrices `X` and `Y` and puts the resulting product into matrix `result`. It then prints the matrix `result` row by row, so it looks like a matrix on the screen.

For this snippet to work, matrices `X`, `Y` and `result` must already be set up--`X` and `Y` with their values, and `result` with the right shape (numbers of rows and columns) and all zero values. Note that there is no error checking in this code, not even that the number of columns of `X` equals the number of rows of `Y`.

The expression `len(X)` returns the number of rows in `X`, while `len(Y[0])` returns the number of columns of `Y`, at least if `X` and `Y` were set up properly. The rest of the code is the standard way to multiply two matrices, with each entry in `result` calculated as the scalar product of a row of `X` with a column of `Y`.

Do you understand matrix multiplication and how Python stores a matrix in a list of lists, or do you need more explanation?

Comment: Thank you! i understand now.

Comment: "but with meaningless values" isn't quite accurate, `results` needs to be the zero matrix

Comment: @JaredGoguen: Yes, you are right. I thought I saw an assignment to zero before the inner loop, as is usually the case. I'll correct my answer. Thanks!